# Where can I find styles.xml and themes.xml?

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-theme, android-styles

The Android [Styles and Themes documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles) points developers to the `styles.xml` and `themes.xml` files because they say the style references are poorly documented.  However, the links are broken.  Where can I find them?

> The R.style reference, however, is not well documented and does not
>   thoroughly describe the styles, so viewing the actual source code for
>   these styles and themes will give you a better understanding of what
>   style properties each one provides. For a better reference to the
>   Android styles and themes, see the following source code: [links
>   broken]

Answer (score 0):

[`themes.xml`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) and [`styles.xml`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) are now available on github
in the following directory:

[`platform_frameworks_base / core / res / res / values`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/values).